# How to get rid of Debug Current Instruction Pointer

Tags: eclipse

Current Instruction Pointer..When I put debugger on a particular location it starts debugging its previous step and then comes to the current location. I can see Current Instruction Pointer with the debugger icon on the another location while the debugger starts.

Please help me I have been trying to get rid of it for last two days.

This is the scenario:

I have put the debugger on **viewattachment**.which comes after **openattachment**.
But when I click on **openattachment** this starts getting debugged and then when I click the **viewattachment** the debugging starts for it..

Why is it going to openattachment? Its a overhead for me. can anyone help me on it?

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

The code is as under..........

```
   else if (getParameters().get("type") != null && getParameters().get("type")[0].equals("**viewattachment**")){
            String elementUid = getParameters().get("elementUid")[0];
            String target = "failure";
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            if (!isUserLoggedIn()){
                target="session";
                obj.put("result", target);
            }
            else{
                if (!isValidUid(cardUid) || !isValidUid(elementUid)){
                    //return "fail";
                    obj.put("result", "fail");
                }
                else {
                    setMessages(msgService.WSIGetAttachments(elementUid));
                    if (!isAccountManager()) {
                        Message msg = getMessages().get(0); 
                        HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
                        try{ 
                            response.getOutputStream().print(obj.toString());                
                        } 
                        catch(IOException e){ 
                            log.error(e);
                        }           
                        response.setContentType(msg.getAttachmentcontentType());
                        response.setHeader("filename", msg.getAttachmentName());
                        response.getWriter().print(obj);
                        response.getWriter().flush();
                        response.getWriter().close();


                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (getParameters().get("type") != null && getParameters().get("type")[0].equals("**openattachment**")){
            String elementUid = getParameters().get("elementUid")[0];
            if (elementUid != null) {//Conversion detail request
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                if (!isValidUid(elementUid)){
                    obj.put("result", "fail");
                    obj.put("message", "Not a valid element");
                }
                else{
                    setMessages(msgService.WSIGetAttachments(elementUid));
                    obj.put("result","success");
                    if (getMessages() != null && getMessages().size() > 0){                 
                        for (Message m : getMessages()){                    
                            JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
                            obj1.put("attachmentname", m.getAttachmentName());
                            obj1.put("elementUid", m.getElementUID());  
                            array.add(obj1);
                        }
                    }
                    obj.put("messages", array);
                    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = ServletActionContext.getResponse(); 
                    try{ 
                        httpResponse.getOutputStream().print(obj.toString());                
                    } 
                    catch(IOException e){ 
                        log.error(e);
                    }           
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is just the place in the code where I am getting this problem....I want to know how can I remove the current location pointer..which goes debugging other line while the breakpoint is placed somewhere else in the same class.....

Answer (score 2):

just right click on the source file and you will fine a "Execute" option choose that , as it runs , in the console window you can click on the stop (red button) this will remove "Debug Current Instruction Pointer"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot move the current location when you are debugging in Eclipse. If you change the source of the method (and hot code replace is working) that is currently being debugged, the debugger will go back to the beginning of the method to allow you to continue execution with the changed method.

I still don't see where "viewattachment" and "openattachment" are in the code you have provided.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @FrancisUpton I am stuck with this too, with one line highlighted, and I have no idea how to get rid of it. Why doesn't it just go away? I'm not debugging anything. I've shut everything down over and over again. I've run the class both from a webapp as well as a main method. I just don't get it.